# Mongo Aggregation filter on collection 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi I am working with mongoDb I have two collections as below:

**Owners**

- name
- address
- familySize
- petId

---

```
[
  {
    "name": "Johnsons",
    "address": "Lambert Street",
    "familySize": 4,
    "petId": "p153ATjs54"
  },
    {
    "name": "Markinsons",
    "address": "Pebble Street",
    "familySize": 2,
    "petId": "G34hts94"
  }
]
```

**Pets**

- animal_Id  `// the foreign key if you may for petId`
- petName
- preferredPlayToy
- vaccinationInfo

---

```
[
  {
    "animal_Id": "G34hts94",
    "petName": "Oscar",
    "preferredPlayToy": "Ball",
    "vaccinationInfo": {
      "vacId": "a-984KA",
      "dosage": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "animal_Id": "p153ATjs54",
    "petName": "Piggy",
    "preferredPlayToy": "Bone",
    "vaccinationInfo": {
      "vacId": "G-397B",
      "dosage": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Now I am actually trying to find all **Owners** who have pet that have **preferredPlayToy** as "ball" 
Below is what I have in the pipeline but I can't seem to get it right:

```
db.owners.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'ms_pets',
            localField: 'petId',
            foreignField: 'aniId',
            as: 'petMaster'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 1,
                    address: 1
        'petMasterData': {
            $filter:{
                input: "$petMaster", 
                as: "master", 
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$master.preferredPlayToy", 'ball' ] } 
            } 
        }
    }
])
```

> It'll also be great if I can pull out the pet name and vaccinationInfo from the Pets table as part of the response.

**Sample Expected:**

```
{
    "name": "Markinsons",
    "address": "Pebble Street",
    "petId": "G34hts94",
    "petMasterData":{

        "petName": "Oscar",
        "vaccinationInfo": {
            "vacId": "a-984KA",
            "dosage": 3
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show sample documents and expected output ?

Comment: @mickl give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to apply both filtering conditions and projection. To convert an array into single subdocument you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) which will also remove `owners` with empty `petMasterData`

```
db.owners.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "ms_pets",
            let: { pet_Id: "$petId" },
            pipeline: [ 
                { $match: { 
                    $expr: { 
                        $and: [ 
                            { $eq: [ "$$pet_Id", "$animal_Id" ] }, 
                            { $eq: [ "$preferredPlayToy", "Ball" ] } ] 
                        } 
                    }
                },
                { $project: { petName: 1, vaccinationInfo: 1, _id: 0 } } 
            ],
            as: "petMasterData"                
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$petMasterData" }
])
```

Comment: quick thing if I only want to filter out the fields that appear in the `petMasterData` how do I do that? I tried "$petMasterData.petName: 1" in the `$project` it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @iam.Carrot modified and simplified my answer